# Inappropriate advertisement

Tags: discussion, advertising

I don't normally even look at the right hand column on SF so never really notice the ads but due to its garish colours (relative to the rest of the page) this one was really hard not to notice.

[image: ad]

I thought only appropriate ads were going to be served on the site and I'm having a really hard time seeing a connection between this one and what SF is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this should be a comment or answer...

I participate on cooking.SE a bit, so I recognize that logo as another SE site.  But since I don't pay attention to any other SE sites, I find some of their ads to be intrusive, e.g. Area51 and Gaming.

I know the idea of the ads is to get people from one SE site to be aware of others that might be of interest, but I think it's a weakness of SE, Inc.'s business model to think that, say, professional sysadmins will also have expert-level advice to give on cooking or biking or car repair or whatever.  (Obviously there are likely to be cross-site experts for some pairings.)

Maybe if they put any and all SE ads inside a less-annoying StackExchange frame, with the site-specific logo much smaller.

Comment: I agree and that SE frame should go way down the bottom of the page, where it won't be just an irritant. Many of us have cross-site interests but few of us have the same ones. Strange as it might seem, I don't come to SF to find out about cooking or excessively pedantic use of the English language or any of the other SE stuff. Maybe it's just my weird way of looking at things but I'd have thought it would be more productive and effective to advertise SE sites in places where people with the relevant interests might go.

Answer (score 3):

The ads for other Stack Exchange sites have always been on the sidebar ads. Usually they're for programmers.se or one of the beta sites, which have much less intrusive colour schemes.

Additionally, we should be seeing a *lot* more relevant ads because the [Community Promotion Ads](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/) have been extended to all SE sites.

Comment: Ok but you'd think that ads for other SE sites would at least look like that's what they are, rather than just an extremely annoying eyesore. Nearly as bad as that idiotic "Do you haz the codez" one.

Comment: I agree with that. Some sort of consistant branding would be great. A Stack Exchange logo in a corner or something, so you can tell at a glance if it's a SE ad or a commercial ad.